# How do I fix this noise coming from my fridge?

Tags: refrigerator, noise

My refrigerator (Bosch B22CT80SNS01) sits in an alcove and has begun intermittently making a noise from what seems to be the inside. At first I thought it was the water filter/lines having air, but I’ve switched the filter and cycled water for a few minutes. Running the water doesn’t stop the noise when it’s happening either, nor does it sputter.

It sounds like it’s behind an inside panel at the top, maybe a fan or something? See video below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJrmo.jpg

Comment: The ice maker or maybe the defrost cycle??

Comment: I took off the grill where the noise was originating and the insulation components behind it. A little motor that opens a door to let cold air flow into the refrigerator from the freezer was making the racket. Looking it up online shows it's the "Refrigerator Air Damper Control Assembly" [here](https://www.searspartsdirect.com/product/7mzltdmh3p-0046-630/id-00798467). I think this is what I need to replace.

Comment: Those do frequently go bad so good job and good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the air damper motor and so replacing the assembly did the trick! No more noise.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for answering your own question. You can click the checkmark next to your answer to indicate it's the "right" one.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the tip!